# How do I use a regex to remove a "." at the end of the a string which may be inside a markup too?

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex that can remove the "." at the end (can be inside a centa or centb) markup and put it infront of

```
String input1 = "this is a &emsp; <centa> test.</centa>" 
String output1 = "this is a .&emsp;<centa> test</centa>"
```

or

```
 String input1b = "this is a &emsp; <centb> test.</centb>" 
    String output1b = "this is a .&emsp;<centb> test</centb>"
```

or

```
String input3 = "this is a &emsp; test." 
String output3 = "this is a .&emsp; test"
```

I can only use replaceAll on the string so, how do I create the pattern in the code below ? and what should the replacement string be ?

```
Pattern rulerPattern1 = Pattern.compile("", Pattern.MULTILINE);
System.out.println(rulerPattern1.matcher(input1).replaceAll(""));
```

This edge case was presented by the requester in comments

```
string input4 = "&ldquo;[<deleted.material>[</deleted.material>]&sect;&ensp;431:10A&ndash;126&em‌​sp;[<deleted.material>]Chemotherapy services.</deleted.material>] <added.material>Cancer treatment.</added.material>test snl."
string output4 = "&ldquo;[<deleted.material>[</deleted.material>]&sect;&ensp;431:10A&ndash;126.&em‌​sp;[<deleted.material>]Chemotherapy services.</deleted.material>] <added.material>Cancer treatment.</added.material>test snl"
```

Comment: Do you have to use regex?

Comment: @ j.rightly, OP states `I can only use replaceAll on the string so` so I'm guessing yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Description

This regex will find find `&emsp;` and move the last dot in the string to just before the `&emsp;`

Regex:  `([&]emsp;[^.]*)\.`

Replace with `.$1`

[image]

Given your input text samples:

```
this is a &emsp; <centa> test.</centa>
this is a &emsp; <centb> test.</centb> 
this is a &emsp; test.
```

This returns the following lines respectivly

```
this is a .&emsp;<centa> test</centa>
this is a .&emsp;<centb> test</centb>
this is a .&emsp; test
```

If you're looking to move the last dot in your string then you can use this

Regex: `([&]em‌​sp;.*)\.`

Replace with  `.$1`

[image]

Given your input text:

```
&ldquo;[<deleted.material>[</deleted.material>]&sect;&ensp;431:10A&ndash;126&em‌​sp;[<deleted.material>]Chemotherapy services.</deleted.material>] <added.material>Cancer treatment.</added.material>test snl.
```

Returns

```
&ldquo;[<deleted.material>[</deleted.material>]&sect;&ensp;431:10A&ndash;126.&em‌​sp;[<deleted.material>]Chemotherapy services.</deleted.material>] <added.material>Cancer treatment.</added.material>test snl
```

Comment: +1 for cool racetrack diagram; is there a tool that generates those?

Comment: @ Edward Falk, yes I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Comment: Could you explain this part ? [^.]*)\

Comment: Sure can, the `[.]` is a character class which match any character that is a dot, by including the up tick `^` I negate expression so that `[^.]` will find any non-dot characters (everything but the dots). This way it forces the regex engine to continue matching all characters until it reaches the dot but does not include the dot.

Comment: Thanks, is there a reason it doesn't remove the ending period from this string but correctly inserts after emsp ? "&ldquo;[<deleted.material>[</deleted.material>]&sect;&ensp;431:10A&ndash;126&emsp;[<deleted.material>]Chemotherapy services.</deleted.material>] <added.material>Cancer treatment.</added.material>test snl.";

Answer (score 1):

> I can only use replaceAll on the string

Ok, weird requirement but here's my solution. I needed to use replaceAll twice to cover with/without tags scenarios.

```
private String parse(final String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("this is a &emsp; <(cent(a|b))> test\\.</\\1>", 
        "this is a .&emsp;<$1> test</$1>")
        .replaceAll("&emsp; test.", ".&emsp; test");
}

@Test
public void centa() {
    // Arrange
    final String input = "this is a &emsp; <centa> test.</centa>";

    // Act
    final String output = parse(input);

    // Assert
    assertEquals("this is a .&emsp;<centa> test</centa>", output);
}

@Test
public void centb() {
    // Arrange
    final String input = "this is a &emsp; <centb> test.</centb>";

    // Act
    final String output = parse(input);

    // Assert
    assertEquals("this is a .&emsp;<centb> test</centb>", output);
}

@Test
public void noTags() {
    // Arrange
    final String input = "this is a &emsp; test.";

    // Act
    final String output = parse(input);

    // Assert
    assertEquals("this is a .&emsp; test", output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to match your code with a single replaceAll. This should satisfy the 3 of your test cases.

Group 1 and 2 are separated, so that we can put a dot within.
Group 2 and 4 are separated, so that we can remove the dot within.

```
Pattern rulerPattern1 = Pattern.compile("([\\W\\w]+)(&emsp;(<cent[ab]>)?[\\W\\w]+)\\.(</cent[ab]>)?", Pattern.MULTILINE);
System.out.println(rulerPattern1.matcher(input1).replaceAll("$1.$2$4"));
```